# Awk - Substring comparison

Tags: awk, comparison, substring

Working native bash code :

```
while read line
do

a=${line:112:7}
b=${line:123:7}

if [[ $a != "0000000" || $b != "0000000" ]]
then
    echo "$line" >> FILE_OT_YHAV
else 
    echo "$line" >> FILE_OT_NHAV
fi

done <$FILE_IN
```

I have the following file (its a dummy), the substrings being checked are both on the 4th field, so nm the exact numbers.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA   XXXXXX BB    CCCCCCC      12312312443430000000
BBBBBBB         AXXXXXX CC    DDDDDDD      10101010000000000000
CCCCCCCCCC C C  QWEQWEE DDD   AAAAAAA     A12312312312312310000
```

I m trying to write an awk script that compares two specific substrings, if either one is not 000000 it outputs the line into File A, if both of them are 000000 it outputs the line into File B, this is the code i have so far :

```
# Before first line.
BEGIN {
print "Awk Started"
FILE_OT_YHAV="FILE_OT_YHAV.test"
FILE_OT_NHAV="FILE_OT_NHAV.test"
FS=""
}

# For each line of input.
{ 
fline=$0
# print "length = @" length($0) "@"
print "length = @" length(fline) "@"
print "##" substr($0,112,7) "##" substr($0,123,7) "##"

if ( (substr($0,112,7) != "0000000") || (substr($0,123,7) != "0000000") )
  print $0 > FILE_OT_YHAV;
else
  print $0 > FILE_OT_NHAV;

}

# After last line.
END {
print "Awk Ended"
}
```

The problem is that when i run it, it :
 a) Treats every line as having a different length
 b) Therefore the substrings are applied to different parts of it (that is why i added the print length stuff before the if, to check on it.

This is a sample output of the line length awk reads and the different substrings :

```
Awk Started
length = @130@
##       ##       ##
length = @136@ 
##0000000##22016  ##
length = @133@
##0000001##16     ##
length = @129@
##0010220##       ##
length = @138@
##0000000##1022016##
length = @136@
##0000000##22016  ##
length = @134@
##0000000##016    ##
length = @137@
##0000000##022016 ##
```

Is there a reason why awk treats lines of the same length as having a different length? Does it have something to do with the spacing of the input file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

After the comments about cleaning the file up with sed, i got this output (and yes now the lines have a different size) :

```
 1  0M-DM-EM-G M-A.M-E.                 @DEH           M-SM-TM-OM-IM-WM-EM-IM-A M-DM-V/M-DM-T/M-TM-AM-P                      01022016                                                             $
 2  110000080103M-CM-EM-QM-OM-MM-TM-A M-A.               6M-AM-HM-GM-MM-A          1055801001102  0000120000012001001142  19500000120   0100M-D000000000000000000000001022016         $
 3  110000106302M-TM-AM-QM-EM-KM-KM-A                 5M-AM-AM-HM-GM-MM-A          1043801001101  0000100000010001001361  19500000100M-IM-SM-O0100M-D000000000000000000000001022016         $
 4  110000178902M-JM-AM-QM-AM-CM-IM-AM-MM-MM-G M-KM-EM-KM-AM-S        71M-AM-HM-GM-MM-A          1136101001101  0000130000013001006061  19500000130   0100M-D000000000000000000000001022016         $
```

Comment: `awk` doesn't lie about such things. you can debug your data with `sed -n '1,4p' myDatFile | cat -nvet` . You'll see `$` at the end of the line, if you see `^M$` at the end of the line, then use `dos2unix myDatFile` to remove dos line endings. (This may solve your problem). ALSO,  you'll see `^I` for any tab chars (that might display normally as (up to) 8 spaces. If that doesn't help, then edit your Q to include the output from above. Good luck.

Comment: Added the sed output after your help, in said output the lines appear to be of a different size. My question is that i scripted something on native bash to run those two comparisons, and the results were correct but it was slow. How can i bring the input file to the right format so i can use awk? (Its like a million times faster according to my count)

Comment: Are you sure about where the 7 zeros are located? Use `awk '{for(i=1;i<length($0);i++){ if (substr($0,i,7) == "0000000") {print NR":"i ":" substr($0,i,7)}}}' data.txt` to see where the 7 zeros are located in your data. Good luck.